# Python - extend enum fields during creation

Tags: python, enums, metaclass

Is it possible extend enum during creation?
Example:

```py
class MyEnum(enum.StrEnum):
    ID = "id"
    NAME = "NAME
```

And I need that after creating this enum contains the next fields:

```
ID = "id"
NAME = "name"
ID_DESC = "-id"
NAME_DESC = "-name"
```

I need this to create custom ordering enum for FastAPI project

Now I have the next way to create new enum

```py
NewEnum = enum.StrEnum(
    f"{name.title()}OrderingEnum",
    [
        (
            f"{ordering_field.upper()}_DESC"
            if ordering_field.startswith("-")
            else ordering_field.upper(),
            ordering_field,
        )
        for ordering_field in itertools.chain(
            values,
            [f"-{field}" for field in values],
        )
    ],
)
```

But I need do this automatically, because each module with model have similar enum. Maybe this is possible to solve my problem using `MetaClass` for my enum class, or override `__new__` method, but I didn't find working solution yet

Comment: It sounds to me like you're using an enum when you should be using a dictionary.

Comment: I used enum to generate `multiple select` for ordering fields on API scheme. In this way frontend see all available ordering fields, and pydantic will raise validation error for invalid values

Comment: Can it do that if the fields are added dynamically?

Comment: @Barmar fields added only once, and enum used after adding extra fields.
Now I did it like in example from my question but it's a lot of copypast because I need similar enum for a few models. And I want to extend enum in other way (but maybe it's impossible)

Comment: Maybe my question's title was incorrect. I renamed this (removed `dinamically` word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancing the `__new__` of `EnumType` (used to be `EnumMeta` and still has that as an alias) will do the job:

```
from enum import EnumMeta, StrEnum

class IDEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, **kwds):
        # add new entries to classdict
        for name in list(classdict._member_names):
            classdict[f'{name}_DESC'] = f'-{classdict[name]}'
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, **kwds)

class IDEnum(StrEnum, metaclass=IDEnumMeta):
    pass
```

and in use:

```
>>> class MyEnum(IDEnum):
...     ID = 'id'
...     NAME = 'name'

>>> list(MyEnum)
[<MyEnum.ID: 'id'>, <MyEnum.NAME: 'name'>, <MyEnum.ID_DESC: '-id'>, <MyEnum.NAME_DESC: '-name'>]
```

This answer currently uses the private `_EnumDict` and its `_member_names` attribute, but they'll be public in 3.13.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: You made my day!
Thanks!